# want to make setup files of my java mysql project

Tags: java, mysql, exe

I have done a restaurant management project with java fxml and MySQL using intellij idea. Now i want to make a setup file like other software available. I want to make sure that one can easily install the setup file in his computer without installing JDK or other things.  And how can i consider my software licence issue? I already tried some jar to exe converter software but failed to do it. Need some help.

Comment: Try this http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E50453_01/doc.80/e50452/build_japps.htm#NBDAG2508 And https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/native_pkg.html

Comment: Might be worth a read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/147181/how-can-i-convert-my-java-program-to-an-exe-file?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Write a custom installer (with native operating system language)

If you are targeting multiple OSs, make for each one "install program" written in its native format. This idea is used by many Java projects, including Netbeans IDE which contains a small C++ runner for windows, linux and other systems. The Netbeans launcher verifies JDK exists and starts up VM with desired arguments. Here you can take a look at it http://hg.netbeans.org/main/file/96711149dcd2/ide/launcher

For example, you write a custom .NET installer for windows that checks if JDK is installed or not, after that it installs your system. The same thing would be for Linux or any other OS.